# How to create hard/soft links in C?

Tags: c, symlink, hardlink

I need to create a hard link to an existing file or directory.
I also need to create a soft/symbolic link to an existing file or directory. This is part of a larger program which is shown below. Commands are executed by typing "-f pathname linkname" and each break argument is a different command. I believe the functions -f, -d and -h have been created correctly so far. However I am having trouble creating these links.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

//Handles filename, absolute pathname
//Need relative pathname for -f
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char command[200], flag[20], pathname[100], linkname[100];
  struct stat st = {0};
  char cmd[200];
  char *token; //Pointer
  int counter = 1; //Counter variable
  FILE *fp;
  char mode2[] = "0750"; //To set the permission of a file/path
  long j;
  char mode[] = "0640"; //To set the permission of a file/path
  long i;

  printf("Enter command: ");
  fgets(cmd, 420, stdin);

  //User input is tokenized to determine the proper commands are entered and executed
  token = strtok(cmd, " "); //Input is tokenized by white spaces.
  if(token == NULL)
  {
        printf("Error with command input.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  strcpy(command, token);

  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if(token != NULL)
      strcpy(flag, token);

  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if(token != NULL)
      strcpy(pathname, token);

  token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  if(token != NULL)
      strcpy(linkname, token);

  //Switch statement to determine which command the user is choosing and execute that command.
  switch(flag[1]) {

 //The f case will create a file who's name is chosen by the user. 
  case 'f':
    fp=fopen(pathname,"w");
      fclose(fp);
      char mode[] = "0640"; //Sets the permission of file to 0640.
      i = strtol(mode, 0, 8);

    if (chmod(pathname, i) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error in chmod(%s, %s) - %d (%s)\n",
                argv[0], pathname, mode, errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    break;

 //The d case will create a new directory chosen by the user.
  case 'd':
      if (stat(pathname, &st) == -1) {
    mkdir(pathname, 0750); //Directory is given permission 0750.
      }

      j = strtol(mode, 0, 8);

    if (chmod (pathname,j) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error in chmod(%s, %s) - %d (%s)\n",
                argv[0], pathname, mode, errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
      break;

 //The h case will create a hardlink to an existing file.
  case 'h':
    char *pathname; //Existing file
    char *linkname; //Name of desired hardlink
    int hlink; //Stores path
    hlink = link(pathname, linkname); //Links linkname to pathname

    if (chmod (pathname,j) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error linking(%s, %s) - %d (%s)\n",
                argv[0], pathname, mode, errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    break;

 //The s case will create a symbol link to an existing file.
  case 's':
    char *pathname;
    char *linkname;
    int slink;
    slink = symlink(pathname, linkname); //Using the symlink function to create a symbolic link of pathname


    if (chmod (pathname,j) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error linking(%s, %s) - %d (%s)\n",
                argv[0], pathname, mode, errno, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as hard or soft links in C. You probably want to ask about the behaviour of a specific operating system.

Comment: "Having trouble".  Can you be more specific?  What fails?  What error messages do you get? (It looks like your code is printing error messages and including `strerror(errno)`, which is good.)

Comment: Try checking the return code (and printing appropriate error messages) after calling `mkdir`, `link`, and `symlink`, just like you already are when calling `chmod`.

Comment: For some operating systems, the source code for the programs that do this is available for you to study. Anyhow, welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask], it provides a few more details to put the criticism you received into context.

Comment: @Swordfish Unix has had soft and hard links for a very long time and those have both been available in C library from way back. He even has the correct functions called in his code (`link()` for hard links and `symlink()` for soft links).

Answer (score 3):

POSIX

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/link.html

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/symlink.html

```
#include <unistd.h>
char *path1 = "/home/cnd/mod1";
char *path2 = "/modules/pass1";
int   status;
...
status = link (path1, path2);
```

Windows

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createhardlinka

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinka

```
BOOL fCreatedLink = CreateHardLink( pszNewLinkName, 
                                    pszExistingFileName, 
                                    NULL ); // reserved, must be NULL
if ( fCreatedLink == FALSE )
{
    ;// handle error condition
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems correct except for the variable shadowing you have in your hard- and soft-link cases.

If we look at the hardlink case, you redefine the `pathname` and `linkname` variables:

```
case 'h':
  char *pathname; //Existing file
  char *linkname; //Name of desired hardlink
  int hlink; //Stores path
  hlink = link(pathname, linkname); //Links linkname to pathname

  if (chmod (pathname,j) < 0)
  {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: error linking(%s, %s) - %d (%s)\n",
              argv[0], pathname, mode, errno, strerror(errno));
      return -1;
  }
  return 0;
  break;
```

Removing those two variables from here, since you have them already defined above, will make the code work.

As mentioned by some commenters, testing `hlink` and printing the error could help.

Note that since you do not initialize the `pathname` and `linkname` variables in that `case` block, the pointers may be garbage or null and it is not unlikely to make your program crash (SEGV).

One thing to do in order to avoid such shadowing is to request the warning. It's super helpful (I do make that mistake once in a while and the warning helps me fix the bug before I ever run my code).

```
gcc -Wshadow ...
```

You may also want to use the `-Wall` which turns on many error checks that you should always fix. When I create code, I also use `-Werror` so if a warning happens, I have to fix it no matter what before everything compiles. Very helpful to fix many bugs very early on.

---

As a side note, it is also now possible to make a *reflink* copy. This is nearly an equivalent to the hardlink, but with the ability to modify one file without modifying the other.

From the [`cp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) command line `clone()` operation:

```
/* Perform the O(1) btrfs clone operation, if possible.
   Upon success, return 0.  Otherwise, return -1 and set errno.  */
static inline int
clone_file (int dest_fd, int src_fd)
{
#ifdef FICLONE
  return ioctl (dest_fd, FICLONE, src_fd);
#else
  (void) dest_fd;
  (void) src_fd;
  errno = ENOTSUP;
  return -1;
#endif
}
```